# how to stop refreshing of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

actually i have  wrote piece of code for detecting the geolocation and based on that geolocation  the currency will change and it's working too but here problem is again and again that piece of code is refreshing the entire page and if i remove that else part the page is refreshing if i keep that else the condition was not working   ,can any one suggest me how to stop that this what i wrote

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //alert("Welcome to our visitors from  "+geoplugin_currencyCode());  
    alert("Welcome to our visitors from  "+geoplugin_countryName());

     $flag=false;
     if($flag===false) {
        var country = geoplugin_countryName();

        if(country === 'India') {
            $('#currency input[name=\'code\']').attr('value', 'INR');
            $('#currency').submit();
            alert('Your currency is set to INR');
        } else {
            $('#currency input[name=\'code\']').attr('value', 'USD');
            $("#currency").change();
            alert('Your currency is set to USD');
        }
   } else {
        return false;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried use your code - and my peage is not reload automatically. Which code refresh your page?

Comment: did u delete that else part if not delete it and try in my page its reloading iam using it in opencart

Comment: You have more than one else... I'm assuming you mean the else containing the `return false;` is that correct?

Comment: yes that return false when i remove that  it continuously reloading

Comment: What is this element `$("#currency")`? Is it a form?

Comment: What is the value of `geoplugin_countryName()`?

Comment: I thinking `$('#currency').submit();` line causing the issue. It's trying to submit the form so page is keeps loading.

Comment: geoplugin_countryName() by using this iam getting the country name bro

Comment: Can you please comment this line `$('#currency').submit();` and have a check. I hope that line is causing the issue?

Comment: no i have tryed that too ,when i commented that the currency symbol was not changing

Comment: Try change $("#currency").submit(); to $("#currency").click();

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function(){
    alert("Welcome to our visitors from  "+geoplugin_countryName());
     $flag=false;
     if($flag===false){
        var country = geoplugin_countryName();
         if(country === "India"){
            $("#currency input[name=\'code\']").attr("value", "INR");
            $("#currency").submit();
            alert("Your currency is set to INR");
            return false;
         } else{
            $("#currency input[name=\'code\']").attr("value", "USD");
            $("#currency").change();
            alert("Your currency is set to USD");
            return false;
         }
   } else{
      return false;
   }
  });
```

Comment: Can you say - what value has 'country' variable in your code ?

Comment: actually  this is the plugin  i have used to get the country name <script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: actually what is happening if you commented out this $("#currency").submit(); it won't change the symbol i mean currency

Comment: Sure, try uncomment this line.

Comment: if uncomment its reloding is there any another way to do that

Comment: What if you change $("#currency").submit(); to $("#currency").change(); ? And can you provide the HTML of #currency element ? Also you can try change submit to $("#currency").click();

Comment: if i change that .submit() to change() it at 1st tym it loads but currency doesn't change  and the click()  is also not working , that currency i have used in html

Comment: i think that problem is at that line only when i change that submit to click its loading only one time but problem is currency not changing

Answer (score 0):

Your codes is fine, but you have to handle it in a different way. For the very first when page loads, let say you got the country as `India`. So now it's go to `if(country === "India"){` codes where it's execute `$("#currency").submit();` line and submit the form. So once form is submitted you have to set `INR` value may be in a hidden field. And then you can add a line of code to verify if the hidden field has `INR` value or not. If it has value `INR` then don't execute the codes.

Let say you have hidden field with id `currency_code`. So now after form submit whatever value you posted from `$("#currency input[name=\'code\']")` just set that value in `#currency_code` input hidden field.

Now check that condition in your codes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //alert("Welcome to our visitors from  "+geoplugin_currencyCode());  
    alert("Welcome to our visitors from  "+geoplugin_countryName());

     $flag=false;
     if($flag===false) {
        var country = geoplugin_countryName();

        if(country === 'India') {
            if($('#currency_code') !== 'INR') {
                $('#currency input[name=\'code\']').attr('value', 'INR');
                $('#currency').submit();
               alert('Your currency is set to INR');
            } else {
               alert('Your currency is already set to INR');
            }
        } else {
            $('#currency input[name=\'code\']').attr('value', 'USD');
            $("#currency").change();
            alert('Your currency is set to USD');
        }
   } else {
        return false;
   }
</script>
```

I'm not sure about all your HTML codes. But this the way you can handle your issue. Hope this will help you.